# Heroku dynos H12, all requests timing out

Tags: python, django, heroku

Dynos completely fail (timeouts) every other day

Hi all, I've been having this issue with Heroku for months now. I have a python/django app, using the 2X dynos (2 of them). I have 8 workers per dyno

Every other day, there will be a huge spike in the response times and it will last for 30 mins to a few hours. All web requests will fail (503s) and Heroku will just tell me its an H12 (request timeout).

On normal times, my p95 for requests are under a second and theres no spikes.

Heres what I've tried:

- Autoscaling dynos with Judoscale
- Provisioning a new/faster database
- Finding out what queries are slow and optimizing them
- Restarting dynos when this happens

Nothing seems to work. Most of the time it just goes away after a while, other times i have to shut the entire app down for a while and restart it.

I havent noticed any change in traffic to the website either. The number of users stays consistent every day. On times where there is a spike of user activity, the dynos are actually fine.

I have tried everything on my side and I'm starting to suspect this is a heroku-specific problem. Has anyone run into this before?